# How to recognize as concatenated characters even if there are large spaces between characters by using EasyOCR?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, ocr, easyocr

I am using [EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR#easyocr) to extract the serial number from an image.

However, as you can see in the picture below, Korean characters are recognized well, but the serial number 11001855 is not recognized properly.

I want to get 11001855 not 8, 5, 5.

[Character recognition result in EasyOCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM04A.png)

It seems that the 11001855 is not recognized because of the space between the numbers.

How can I get it to be recognized as 11001855 instead of 8, 5, 5 even if there is a space?

or What should I study to handle this problem?

if you have any idea please let me know.
Thank you :)